# How to use sweetalert2 in nuxt with typescript?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, sweetalert2

Previously I had configured my nuxt project without configuring typescript, so I installed sweetalert2 for nuxt according to this documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-sweetalert2 everything was working fine, then I set typescript in the same project and I have errors in the sweetalert

The error I get is:

```
 Property '$swal' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, { dinamic: { message: string; }; addFile: boolean; fields: { key: string; label: string; sortable: boolean; }[]; loading: boolean; dialogVisible: boolean; title: string; message: string; reason: boolean; ... 28 more ...; html: string; }, { ...; }, { ...; }, Readonly<...>>
```

The way I am using it is:

```
this.$swal({
  title: "Has been deleted",
  text: "the record you are accessing no longer exists",
  type: "warning",
  confirmButtonText: "OK"
});
```

The configuration that I have made of typescript in nuxt is this: https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/es/guide/setup/

Comment: `dinamic`? Isn't it a typo somewhere?

Comment: I have several typescript errors in my component, which I am correcting, but I don't know where else this error could be or I don't know if I should configure some typescript

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't added in `tsconfig.json` in types  "vue-sweetalert2"

Answer (score 0):

Do this setup: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2
in additional nuxt section you need to add to

```
//tsconfig.json
"types": [
    "vue-sweetalert2"
  ],
```